# Domain of definition of a Lagrangian in classical field theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle, variational-calculus, classical-field-theory

In classical field theory one has the action:
$$S[\phi] = \int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}}\int_{\Omega}\mathcal{L}(t,x,\phi(t,x),\dot{\phi}(t,x),\nabla\phi(t,x))dxdt$$
and we want to obtain the Euler-Lagrange equations for the Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$. In the physics literature, one usually takes the first variation with respect to a test field $\psi$ and considers the fields $\phi$ to be sufficiently differentiable and regular. To obtain the desired Euler-Lagrange equations, one assumes $\psi(t_{0})=\psi(t_{1}) = 0$ and that it has fast decay so the surface integrals obtained by using integration by parts vanish.

I want to understand better this argument under a more *rigorous* way. The way I see it, the set $\Omega$ is there to make things well-defined, but the final argument of the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation is that the equations follow because the analysis hold for every set $\Omega$. In my point of view, a better way of making sense of this is by using the following well-known result from analysis: if a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous (or smooth) and satisfies:
$$\int f(x)g(x)dx = 0$$
for every compactly supported $g: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$, then $f = 0$.

It seems more reasonable for me to use this result instead of the usual "holds for every set $\Omega$" argument. If we fix $\Omega$, we can perform the calculations that lead to the Euler-Lagrange equation (for fields) by using compactly supported functions on $[t_{0},t_{1}]\times \Omega$. But this raises the question: what is a typical $\Omega$?

So my question is: is anything wrong with my reasoning? And if not, what is a typical $\Omega$ for a field theory? Open? Closed? Convex?

Comment: It is not very clear your intention. Do you want to produce the EL equations in the whole spacetime? In the portion $[t,t']\times\Omega$ or what? Moreover, are you looking for the mere equations or for the solutions of them? After a precise statement it should be possible to answer.

Comment: I mean, what is the form of a precise statement you expect to be true? For instsnce: *the field $\phi$ satisfies the E L equations in a region $B$ of the soacetime if and only if it is a stationary point of the functional...*

Comment: @ValterMoretti thanks for your comments. My intention is to derive the Euler-Lagrange equation for classical fields in full mathematical terms. I understand that, when one studies classical field theory from a mathematical point of view, the usual approach is to consider fields in manifolds, fiber bundles etc, but I have no background in algebraic topology. So, I want a more "functional analysis" approach, even if it is limited in terms of what are the fields it represents.

Comment: For example, the Klein-Gordon equation and Dirac equation are eqs. that, in my view, can be deduced from this approach, and it would be enough for me at the moment. Moreover, it seems more closely related to what physicists actually do in their textbooks.

Comment: The main problems are: the definition of a field is and how to derive EL equations. A field is usually defined (if I'm not mistaken) as a function $\phi$ defined on spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and which is sufficiently smooth and regular. I am assuming it is part of a locally convex space, for instance. The first variation is then the Gateaux derivative in some direction $\psi$. The references I know define the action $S$ as in my post, for some time-interval $[t_{0},t_{1}]$ and "region" $\Omega$. I want to better specify this region and use the theorem in my post to derive EL-equations.

Comment: It is not clear enough. A way to derive the equations is simply to state them. I suspect that you would like to **prove** a statement like this *the function $\phi$... is a solution of EL equations on $B$ if and only if it is a stationary point of the functional...*.

Comment: @ValterMoretti yes, precisely! My point is to define a classical field and where it lives, the action and Lagrangian and to prove EL-equations from the variational principle, which I understand is obtained by taking the Gateaux derivative of the action at zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us consider a region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^4$, viewed as classical or relativistic spacetime in local coordinates. We suppose that $\Omega$ is open and non-empty.

**PROPOSITION**.
*Let us focus on a map ${\cal L}: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$  of class $C^2$ and on the functional
$$I[\phi] := \int_{\Omega} {\cal L}(x,\phi(x), \partial \phi(x)) d^4x$$
defined for every $\phi:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi \in C^2(\Omega)$.*

*The following fact holds, for every $\phi_0 \in  C^2(\Omega)$ and every $\eta \in C^2(\Omega)$ whose support is included in $\Omega$.*

$$\left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon =0} I[\phi_0 + \epsilon\eta] :=\left\langle \left.\frac{\delta I}{\delta \phi}\right|_{\phi_0}, \eta \right\rangle$$
*exists and defines a linear function in the variable $\eta$, where
$$\left\langle\left.\frac{\delta I}{\delta \phi}\right|_{\phi_0}, \eta \right\rangle = 
\int_{\Omega}\left[\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \phi} - \partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial_\mu \phi }\right) \right]|_{\phi_0} \eta\:  d^4x \:.$$
In particular $\phi_0$ satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equations on $\Omega$*

$$\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \phi}|_{\phi_0} - \partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial_\mu \phi }|_{\phi_0}\right)=0$$
*if and only if
$$\left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon =0} I[\phi_0 + \epsilon\eta]=0\quad \mbox{for every $\eta \in C^2(\Omega)$ compactly supported in $\Omega$.}\tag{1}$$*

**Remark**. The usual way to write down (1) is
$$\left.\frac{\delta I}{\delta \phi}\right|_{\phi_0} =0$$
and the notation $\delta \phi$ is very often used in place of $\eta$.

The proof of the above proposition is elementary: the first statement immediately arises by integrating by parts, the second one is a trivial consequence of the following result (you already stated): If $f \in C^0(\Omega)$, then
$$\int_\Omega f(x) \eta(x) d^nx =0 \quad \mbox{for all $\eta \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ compactly supported in $\Omega$}$$
is equivalent to $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \Omega$.

If you want adding some further (actually here non-necessary mathematical machinery) you can interpret $\left.\frac{\delta I}{\delta \phi}\right|_{\phi_0}$ in terms of  Gateaux derivative of $I$. Furthermore

1. $\Omega$ can be taken of the form $(t_1,t_2) \times \Omega_0$.
2. One can also replace $(t_1,t_2)$ for $[t_1,t_2]$ with trivial changes and to assume that $\Omega_0 = \mathbb{R}^3$.
3. The constraint that $\eta$ has compact support in $\Omega$ can be replaced by the request that $\eta=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ if $\Omega$ is the closure of an open set with regular orientable boundary. This framework can be adapted to the case $\Omega = [t_0,t_1]\times \Omega_0$ with trivial changes.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. I think I was going in the right direction. Just for the record, it seems I can also consider $C^{k}(\Omega)$ with $k \ge 2$ and $\Omega$ compact without loosing anything, right? In this case I would have a Banach/Locally convex space and your directional derivative (second relation) would be simply the Gateaux derivative of $I$ as you mentioned. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes and $k=2$ is just the minimal case which permits everything to hold without many efforts.

Comment: Right, thank you. I remember that, when deriving the EL-eqs. you have to use integration by parts on both the time and $\nabla$ derivatives. The first would lead to a term which is an integral over $x$ with the test function $\eta$ evaluated at $t_{0}$ and $t_{1}$ and the second would lead a surface integral. The hypothesis on $\eta$ must be such that both these integrals vanish. I thought if I used $\Omega$ and $\eta$ compactly supported on $\Omega$ I wouldn't necessarily have, say $\eta(t_{0}) = \eta(t_{1}) = 0$. Maybe its support could contain, say, $t_{0}$ or $t_{1}$?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote these alternative formulations need trivial readaptations. The goal is just to be able to drop boundary terms and everything gives rise to this possibility is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**

I agree that @Valter Moretti answered the question. Yet, I am putting down a second proof on this subject. This is because, in my opinion, the definitions that are given here all together and prior to the proposition, are clearer than the way it is offered up to now. In addition, I offer a (non-formal) proof by contradiction that answers of one of the OP's questions that regards the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations [1]. I further believe that this is a crucially important problem for students as they transition beyond classical electrodynamics. Therefore, having two solutions is welcome.

**Definitions**

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{1+3}$.

Let $\partial \Omega$ be the boundary of $\Omega$.

Let $x = (x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3)$, where $x \in \Omega$.

Let $k = 0,1,2,3$.

For each $k$, let $A^k : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of four variables and of class $C^2$ that assigns each tuple $\left(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\right)$ a value $A^k\!\left(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\right)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

For each $k$, let $\partial_i A^k : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be a function of four variables and of class $C^2$ (or maybe $C^1$) that assigns each tuple $\left(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\right)$ a value $\partial_i A\!\left(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\right)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Let $L : \Omega\times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of four coordinates, four generalized coordinates, and the $4^2$ partial derivatives of the generalized coordinates with respect to the coordinates that assigns each tuple $\Biggl(x^\mu, A^\nu\!\left(x^\mu\right),    
\partial_\mu A^\nu\!\left(x^\mu\right)
\Biggr)$ a value
$L\!\Biggl(x^\mu, A^\nu\!\left(x^\mu\right),    
\partial_\mu A^\nu\!\left(x^\mu\right)
\Biggr) $ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $L$ be a function of class $C^2$ with respect to each and every one of its arguments.

For each $k$, let $\eta^k : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be each and every function of four variables that is of class $C^2$, that is zero over $\partial \Omega$, and that assigns each tuple $\left(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\right)$ a value $\eta^k\!\left(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\right)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

For each $k$, let $\partial_i \eta^k : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be a function of four variables and of class $C^2$ (or maybe $C^1$) that assigns each tuple $\left(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\right)$ a value $\partial_i \eta^k\!\left(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\right)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$

**Proposition**

The tuple $\left(A^0, A^1,A^2,A^3\right)$ is stationary if, and only if,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial  t }\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial   \dot{A}^k   }
= \frac{\partial L}{\partial A^k }
-
 \partial_i\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial\left(  \partial_i \,A^k   \right)} \qquad \text{for}~k = 0, 1,2,3
.
\end{align*}

**Proof**

We wish to find a function $\vec{A} : \mathbf{R}^{1+3} \to \mathbf{R}^4$ which satisfies the boundary conditions $\vec{A}(\partial\Omega) = g(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$, and which extremizes the functional
\begin{align*}
J[A^0,A^1,A^2,A^3] 
&= 
\int_\Omega 
L\!\bigl(x^0,\ldots,x^3,   A^0(x^0,\ldots,x^3), \ldots, A^3(x^0,\ldots,x^3), 
\\
&\quad\qquad \partial_0\, A_0(x^0,\ldots,x^3), \ldots,  \partial_3\, A^0(x^0,\ldots,x^3), \ldots,
\\
&\quad\qquad 
\partial_0\, A^3(x^0,\ldots,x^3), \ldots,  \partial_3\, A^3(x^0,\ldots,x^3) \bigr)\, \mathrm{d}x^0\,\mathrm{d}x^1\,\mathrm{d}x^2\,\mathrm{d}x^3 . 
\end{align*}

If $\vec{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A^0  & A^1 &   A^2 & A^3
\end{bmatrix}
$  extremizes the functional subject to the boundary conditions, then any slight perturbation of $ \vec{A} $ that preserves the boundary values must either increase $J$ (if $\vec{A}$ is a minimizer) or decrease $J$ (if $\vec{A}$ is a maximizer).

Let
$$\begin{bmatrix} A^0  + \varepsilon \,  \eta^0, &
 A^1  + \varepsilon \,  \eta^1,
 &
  A^2  + \varepsilon \,  \eta^2,
  &
   A^3  + \varepsilon \,  \eta^3
   \end{bmatrix}$$ be the result of such a perturbation $\varepsilon \,\vec{\eta}$ of  $\vec{A}$, where $\varepsilon$ is small and $\vec{\eta} : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ is a   differentiable multivariable vector-valued function satisfying $\vec{\eta} (\partial\Omega)  = 0$. Then define
$$ \Phi(\varepsilon) =  J[\vec{A}+\varepsilon\,\vec{\eta}] = \int_\Omega 
L\!\left(x^0,\ldots,x^3,\vec{A}(\vec{x})+\varepsilon\,\vec{\eta}(\vec{x}), \vec{A}_0(\vec{x})+\varepsilon\,\vec{\eta}_0(\vec{x}), \ldots, \vec{A}_3(\mathbf{x})+\varepsilon\,\vec{\eta}_3(\mathbf{x})\right)\, \mathrm{d}^n\mathbf{x} \ .$$
We now wish to calculate the  total derivative  of $ \Phi$  with respect to $\varepsilon$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d} \Phi}{\mathrm{d} \varepsilon} 
&= 
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\varepsilon}\int_\Omega L\!\bigl(x^0,\ldots,x^3,   
\\
&\qquad \qquad 
A^0 +\epsilon\,\eta^0, A^1 +\epsilon\,\eta^1, A^2 +\epsilon\,\eta^2, A^3 +\epsilon\,\eta^3, 
\\
&\qquad\qquad 
\frac{\partial A^0 +\epsilon\,\eta^0}{\partial x^0}, \frac{\partial A^1 +\epsilon\,\eta^1}{\partial x^0}, \frac{\partial A^2 +\epsilon\,\eta^2}{\partial x^0} , 
\frac{\partial A^3 +\epsilon\,\eta^3}{\partial x^0} , 
\\
&\qquad\qquad 
\frac{\partial A^0 +\epsilon\,\eta^0}{\partial x^1}, \frac{\partial A^1 +\epsilon\,\eta^1}{\partial x^1}, \frac{\partial A^2 +\epsilon\,\eta^2}{\partial x^1} , 
\frac{\partial A^3 +\epsilon\,\eta^3}{\partial x^1} , 
\\
&\qquad\qquad 
\frac{\partial A^0 +\epsilon\,\eta^0}{\partial x^2}, \frac{\partial A^1 +\epsilon\,\eta^1}{\partial x^2}, \frac{\partial A^2 +\epsilon\,\eta^2}{\partial x^2} , 
\frac{\partial A^3 +\epsilon\,\eta^3}{\partial x^2} , 
\\
&\qquad\qquad 
\frac{\partial A^0 +\epsilon\,\eta^0}{\partial x^3}, \frac{\partial A^1 +\epsilon\,\eta^1}{\partial x^3}, \frac{\partial A^2 +\epsilon\,\eta^2}{\partial x^3} , 
\frac{\partial A^3 +\epsilon\,\eta^3}{\partial x^3} \bigr)
\\
&= 
\int_\Omega    
\eta^0\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^0 +\epsilon\,\eta^0}
+
\eta^1\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^1 +\epsilon\,\eta^1}
+
\eta^2\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^2 +\epsilon\,\eta^2}
+
\eta^3\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^3 +\epsilon\,\eta^3}
\\
&\qquad\qquad 
\frac{\partial  \eta^0}{\partial x^0}
\,\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^0 +\epsilon\,\eta^0}{\partial x^0}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^1}{\partial x^0}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^1 +\epsilon\,\eta^1}{\partial x^0}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^2}{\partial x^0}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^2 +\epsilon\,\eta^2}{\partial x^0}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^3}{\partial x^0}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^3 +\epsilon\,\eta^3}{\partial x^0}}
\\
&\qquad\qquad 
\frac{\partial  \eta^0}{\partial x^1}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^0 +\epsilon\,\eta^0}{\partial x^1}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^1}{\partial x^1}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^1 +\epsilon\,\eta^1}{\partial x^1}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^2}{\partial x^1}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^2 +\epsilon\,\eta^2}{\partial x^1}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^3}{\partial x^1}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^3 +\epsilon\,\eta^3}{\partial x^1}}
\\
&\qquad\qquad 
\frac{\partial  \eta^0}{\partial x^2}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^0 +\epsilon\,\eta^0}{\partial x^2}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^1}{\partial x^2}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^1 +\epsilon\,\eta^1}{\partial x^2}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^2}{\partial x^2}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^2 +\epsilon\,\eta^2}{\partial x^2}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^3}{\partial x^2}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^3 +\epsilon\,\eta^3}{\partial x^2}}
\\
&\qquad\qquad 
\frac{\partial  \eta^0}{\partial x^3}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^0 +\epsilon\,\eta^0}{\partial x^3}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^1}{\partial x^3}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^1 +\epsilon\,\eta^1}{\partial x^3}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^2}{\partial x^3}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^2 +\epsilon\,\eta^2}{\partial x^3}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^3}{\partial x^3}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^3 +\epsilon\,\eta^3}{\partial x^3}}
\bigr)
\\
&\,\,\qquad
 \mathrm{d}x^0\,\mathrm{d}x^1\,\mathrm{d}x^2\,\mathrm{d}x^3
\ . 
\end{align*}
The second line follows from the fact that $x_1, \ldots,x_n$  does not depend on $\varepsilon $, i.e. $ \frac{\mathrm{d} x_1}{\mathrm{d} \varepsilon} = \cdots = \frac{\mathrm{d} x_n}{\mathrm{d} \varepsilon} = 0$. Next, when $\varepsilon = 0$, $\Phi$ has an  extremum value, so that
\begin{align*}
\left.
\frac{\mathrm{d} \Phi}{\mathrm{d} \varepsilon} 
\right|_{\epsilon=0}
&= 
\int_\Omega    
\Biggl(
\eta^0\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^0 }
+
\left[
\frac{\partial  \eta^0}{\partial x^0}
\,\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x^0}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^0}{\partial x^1}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x^1}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^0}{\partial x^2}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x^2}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^0}{\partial x^3}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x^3}}
\right]
\\
&\qquad 
+
\eta^1\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^1  }
+
\left[
\frac{\partial  \eta^1}{\partial x^0}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^1  }{\partial x^0}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^1}{\partial x^1}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^1  }{\partial x^1}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^1}{\partial x^2}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^1  }{\partial x^2}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^1}{\partial x^3}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^1  }{\partial x^3}}
\right]
\\
&\qquad 
+
\eta^2\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^2  }
+
\left[
\frac{\partial  \eta^2}{\partial x^0}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^2  }{\partial x^0}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^2}{\partial x^1}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^2  }{\partial x^1}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^2}{\partial x^2}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^2  }{\partial x^2}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^2}{\partial x^3}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^2  }{\partial x^3}}
\right]
\\
&\qquad 
+\eta^3\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^3  }
+
\left[
\frac{\partial  \eta^3}{\partial x^0}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^3  }{\partial x^0}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^3}{\partial x^1}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^3  }{\partial x^1}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^3}{\partial x^2}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^3  }{\partial x^2}}
+
\frac{\partial  \eta^3}{\partial x^3}
\,
\frac{\partial L}{ \frac{\partial A^3 }{\partial x^3}}
\right]
\Biggr)
\\
&\,\,\qquad
 \mathrm{d}x^0\,\mathrm{d}x^1\,\mathrm{d}x^2\,\mathrm{d}x^3 =0
\ . 
\end{align*}
This can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\left.
\frac{\mathrm{d} \Phi}{\mathrm{d} \varepsilon} 
\right|_{\epsilon=0}
&= 
\int_\Omega    
\Biggl(
\eta^0\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^0 }
+
\left[
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{x}\eta^0 \cdot  \boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x}} L 
\right]
\\
&\qquad 
+
\eta^1\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^1  }
+
\left[
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{x}\eta^1 \cdot  \boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^1  }{\partial x}} L 
\right]
\\
&\qquad 
+
\eta^2\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^2  }
+
\left[
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{x}\eta^2 \cdot  \boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^2  }{\partial x}} L 
\right]
\\
&\qquad 
+\eta^3\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^3  }
+
\left[
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{x}\eta^3 \cdot  \boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^3  }{\partial x}} L 
\right]
\Biggr)
\, 
 \mathrm{d}x^0\,\mathrm{d}x^1\,\mathrm{d}x^2\,\mathrm{d}x^3 =0 
\ . 
\end{align*}
From a corrollary of the divergence theorem [2], I know that
$$
 \iiint_V\left[\mathbf{F}\cdot \left(\nabla g\right) + g \left(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}\right)\right] \mathrm{d}V= 
\iint_S g\mathbf{F} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \mathrm{d}S.$$
Applying this to the bracketed term in the topmost line of my integral,  I have, for example, that
$$
 \iiint_\Omega\left[\left(\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x \eta^0\right) \cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
\right] \mathrm{d}\Omega
=
-
 \iiint_\Omega\left(  \eta^0 \left[\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x\cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
\right]\right) \mathrm{d}\Omega
+ 
\iint_{\partial \Omega} \eta^0\,\left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
 \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}\, \mathrm{d}S.$$
Since  by construction $\eta^0 (\partial\Omega)  = 0$, therefore
$$
 \iiint_\Omega\left[\left(\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x \eta^0\right) \cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
\right] \mathrm{d}\Omega
=
-
 \iiint_\Omega\left(  \eta^0 \left[\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x\cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
\right]\right) \mathrm{d}\Omega
.$$
Thus, I have that
\begin{align*}
\left.
\frac{\mathrm{d} \Phi}{\mathrm{d} \varepsilon} 
\right|_{\epsilon=0}
&= 
\int_\Omega    
\Biggl(
  \eta^0 \left[
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^0 }
-
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x\cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
\right] 
\\
&\qquad \,\,
+
  \eta^1 \left[
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^1 }
-
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x\cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^1  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
\right] 
\\
&\qquad \,\,
+
  \eta^2 \left[
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^2 }
-
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x\cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^2  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
\right] 
\\
&\qquad \,\,
+
  \eta^3 \left[
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^3 }
-
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x\cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^3  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
\right] 
\Biggr)
\, 
 \mathrm{d}x^0\,\mathrm{d}x^1\,\mathrm{d}x^2\,\mathrm{d}x^3  = 0
\ . 
\end{align*}
Now, I address another of the OP's questions that regards the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations. Each of the bracketed terms must be equal to zero. This can be proven by contradiction in the following way. If each bracketed terms is not zero, then since each $\eta^i$ is arbitrary, choose each $\eta^i$ to be positive where the bracketed term it multiplies is positive, and negative where the bracketed term it multiplies is negative. Then the integrand is positive so that the integral cannot be zero. This contradicts the statement that the integral is zero for every $\eta^0$, every $\eta^1$, every $\eta^2$, and every $\eta^3$.

We thus have the following four Euler-Lagrange equations:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^0 }
-
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x\cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
&= 0.
\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^1 }
-
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x\cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^1  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
&= 0.
\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^2 }
-
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x\cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^2  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
&= 0.
\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A^3 }
-
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_x\cdot \left(
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial A^3  }{\partial x}} L 
\right)
&= 0.
\end{align*}
This can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial  t }\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial  t }}
&= \frac{\partial L}{\partial A^0 }
-
\sum_{i=1}^3 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{\partial A^0  }{\partial x^i}}
.
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial  t }\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{\partial A^1  }{\partial  t }}
&= \frac{\partial L}{\partial A^1 }
-
\sum_{i=1}^3 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{\partial A^1  }{\partial x^i}}
.
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial  t }\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{\partial A^2  }{\partial  t }}
&= \frac{\partial L}{\partial A^2 }
-
\sum_{i=1}^3 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{\partial A^2  }{\partial x^i}}
.
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial  t }\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{\partial A^3  }{\partial  t }}
&= \frac{\partial L}{\partial A^3 }
-
\sum_{i=1}^3 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{\partial A^3  }{\partial x^i}}
.
\end{align*}
Or, more compactly, with Einstein notation as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial  t }\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{A}^k   }
= \frac{\partial L}{\partial A^k }
-
 \partial_i\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial\left(  \partial_i \,A^k   \right)} \quad \text{for}~k = 0, 1,2,3
.
$$

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_the_calculus_of_variations

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Corollaries